# Scrollviewer inside tabItem using WPF Prism

Tags: wpf, prism, tabitem

I am using wpf Prism Controller to add multiple tabs to my view in wpf.
But sometimes when my view is large i want a scrollviewer in my tab item that can scoll horizontally. How can i acieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your xaml. But ensure that your row definitions are set to auto

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TabControl>

        </TabControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```